# creating a hash with elements from a different array of hashes in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

In a bootcamp exercise, we were given this array:

```
library = [
  {
    "title" => "Hitchhiker's Guide", 
    "Author" => "Douglas Adams", 
    "categories" => [ "comedy", "fiction", "british"]
  },
  {
    "title" => "Pride and Prejudice", 
    "Author" => "Jane Austen", 
    "categories" => [ "morality", "fiction", "society", "british"]
  },
  {
    "title" => "Search Inside Yourself", 
    "Author" => "Chade-Meng Tan", 
    "categories" => [ "self improvement", "non-fiction", "mindfulness", "business"]
  },
  {
    "title" => "Benjamin Franklin: An American Life", 
    "Author" => "Walter Isaacson", 
    "categories" => [ "non-fiction", "history", "founding fathers"]
  },
  {
    "title" => "Glengarry Glen Ross", 
    "Author" => "David Mamet", 
    "categories" => [ "play", "fiction", "drama"]
  }
]
```

and we need to make a new hash with the categories as the elements, and the titles as the values.

Was able to figure out how to make a `category_hash`, but I can't figure out how to append the titles to each category. Here is my code:

```
category_hash = {}
sub_category = []

library.each do |book|
  book["categories"].each do |category|
    sub_category << category
  end
  sub_category.each do |index|
    category_hash[index] = "I'm not sure how to append the titles here"
  end
end

p category_hash
```

Can someone help me figure out this step?

Comment: You need to clarify (with an edit) what you mean by, "...with the categories as the elements...". Firstly, you mean "keys" rather than "elements". You will see that not all answers interpreted that the same way. To date, one answer assume "categories" are the values associated with the keys `"categories"` in the  elements (hashes)  of `library`; two answers assume "categories" are the strings included in one or more values of  "categories" in the elements of `library` ("comedy", "fiction", "british",  "morality", "society" and so on). I'm guessing you intended the latter interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
library.each_with_object({}) do |hash, result|
  result[hash['categories']] = hash['title']
end
# {
#   ["comedy", "fiction", "british"]=>"Hitchhiker's Guide",
#   ["morality", "fiction", "society", "british"]=>"Pride and Prejudice",
#   ["self improvement", "non-fiction", "mindfulness", "business"]=>"Search Inside Yourself",
#   ["non-fiction", "history", "founding fathers"]=>"Benjamin Franklin: An American Life",
#   ["play", "fiction", "drama"]=>"Glengarry Glen Ross"
# }
```

Comment: Suppose another hash were added to `librar` containing the key-value pair `"categories" => [ "comedy", "fiction", "british"]`. What then? See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it, which is less efficient than @AndreyDeineko's answer.

```
library.map{|h| h.values_at("categories", "title")}.to_h
```

Result:

```
{
  ["comedy", "fiction", "british"]=>"Hitchhiker's Guide", 
  ["morality", "fiction", "society", "british"]=>"Pride and Prejudice",
  ["self improvement", "non-fiction", "mindfulness", "business"]=>"Search Inside Yourself",
  ["non-fiction", "history", "founding fathers"]=>"Benjamin Franklin: An American Life",
  ["play", "fiction", "drama"]=>"Glengarry Glen Ross"
}
```

In case you wanted it to be distributed by the `"category"` attribute (which, of course, would be dependent on the order of the hash items in the array; I assume you meant later one has priority over an earlier one):

```
library.each_with_object({}) do
  |h, result| h["categories"].each_with_object(result) do
    |k, result| result[k] = h["title"]
  end
end
```

Result:

```
{
  "comedy"=>"Hitchhiker's Guide",
  "fiction"=>"Glengarry Glen Ross",
  "british"=>"Pride and Prejudice",
  "morality"=>"Pride and Prejudice",
  "society"=>"Pride and Prejudice",
  "self improvement"=>"Search Inside Yourself",
  "non-fiction"=>"Benjamin Franklin: An American Life", 
  "mindfulness"=>"Search Inside Yourself",
  "business"=>"Search Inside Yourself",
  "history"=>"Benjamin Franklin: An American Life",
  "founding fathers"=>"Benjamin Franklin: An American Life",
  "play"=>"Glengarry Glen Ross",
  "drama"=>"Glengarry Glen Ross"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a list of each book in a category, and a book to appear in multiple categories, you can attach a [default_proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) when you [initialize the Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) to set all unknown keys to contain an array as a value. Then you simply iterate each book in the library and add it's title to the list for every category it's in:

```
# Pass the category hash a default proc, which will be called
# whenever a key it doesn't have is accessed. So, when you
# encounter a brand new category, it'll already be set up with
# an array
category_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
library.each do |book|
  book['categories'].each do |category|
    # since we passed the default, no worrying, an array will be
    # there and we can just add our value into it
    category_hash[category] << book['title']
  end
end

puts category_hash
```

Result:

```
{
  "comedy"=>["Hitchhiker's Guide"],
  "fiction"=>["Hitchhiker's Guide", "Pride and Prejudice", "Glengarry Glen Ross"],
  "british"=>["Hitchhiker's Guide", "Pride and Prejudice"],
  "morality"=>["Pride and Prejudice"],
  "society"=>["Pride and Prejudice"],
  "self improvement"=>["Search Inside Yourself"],
  "non-fiction"=>["Search Inside Yourself", "Benjamin Franklin: An American Life"],
  "mindfulness"=>["Search Inside Yourself"],
  "business"=>["Search Inside Yourself"],
  "history"=>["Benjamin Franklin: An American Life"],
  "founding fathers"=>["Benjamin Franklin: An American Life"],
  "play"=>["Glengarry Glen Ross"],
  "drama"=>["Glengarry Glen Ross"]
}
```

There's also `each_with_object` so you could modify this to

```
result = library.each.with_object(Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }) do |book, category_hash|
  book['categories'].each do |category|
    # since we passed the default, no worrying, an array will be
    # there and we can just add our value into it
    category_hash[category] << book['title']
  end
end
puts result
```

which would return the `category_hash` and, to save that last line of code:

```
puts(library.each.with_object(Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }) do |book, category_hash|
  book['categories'].each do |category|
    # since we passed the default, no worrying, an array will be
    # there and we can just add our value into it
    category_hash[category] << book['title']
  end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variant of other answers.

```
library = [
  {title: "Hitch Guide", by: "Doug", cats: ["comedy", "fiction", "british"]},
  {title: "P and P",     by: "Jane", cats: ["morality", "fiction", "british"]},
  {title: "Searchin'",   by: "Chad", cats: ["non-fiction", "morality", "gps"]},
  {title: "Crazy Ben",   by: "Walt", cats: ["non-fiction", "comedy", "dads"]}
]
  # => [{:title=>"Hitch Guide", :by=>"Doug", :cats=>["comedy", "fiction", "british"]},
  #     {:title=>"P and P", :by=>"Jane", :cats=>["morality", "fiction", "british"]},
  #     {:title=>"Searchin'", :by=>"Chad", :cats=>["non-fiction", "morality", "gps"]},
  #     {:title=>"Crazy Ben", :by=>"Walt", :cats=>["non-fiction", "comedy", "dads"]}]

library.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  title = g[:title]
  g[:cats].each { |c| (h[c] ||= []) << title }
end
  #=> {"comedy"=>["Hitch Guide", "Crazy Ben"],
  #    "fiction"=>["Hitch Guide", "P and P"],
  #    "british"=>["Hitch Guide", "P and P"],
  #    "morality"=>["P and P", "Searchin'"],
  #    "non-fiction"=>["Searchin'", "Crazy Ben"],
  #    "gps"=>["Searchin'"],
  #    "dads"=>["Crazy Ben"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would normally do it and I think it's the simplest possible way, although the each_with_object trick seen above is neat too.

```
new_hash = {}

library.each do |hash| 
  hash["categories"].each do |category|
    new_hash[category] ||= []
    new_hash[category] << hash["title"]
  end
end
```